# Seperating Business and UI Logic in C# using dotnet framework. How can I refactor this project?

Tags: c#, .net, properties

I am working on a c# project involving a bakery.  The prompt stated that I have to :

1. Use multiple class files
2. Red Green Refactor WorkFlow
3. Use Auto-implemented properties.
4. Separate UI and Business Logic.

I understand auto implemented properties but I got kinda lost writing the code.  I really need some help refactoring.

https://github.com/FaisalRana/CSharp.Bakery <-- here is a link to my repo

`````
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Bakery.Models
{
  public class Program
  {
    public static void Main()
    {
      Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
      Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
      string bakeryAscii = @"
                          ....
                      .'      `.
                    .' .-'``-._ `.
                    |  / -    - ` |
                    / |'<o>  <o> | \
                    (|    '`    |) 
                      \  -==-  /   
                       `.____.'    
                        |    |     
                  _ _.'`-.__.-'`._/_
                .'| |`-.  /\  .-'| |`.
              _.'   \ \  `'  `'  / /   `._
            { `.    | `-.____.-' |    .' }
            /`. `./ /   __  __   \ \.' .'\
            /   `.| |   /  \/  \   | |.'   \
          (    (  \ \  \      /  / /  )    )
            `.   \  Y|   `.  .'   |Y  /   .'
              \   \ ||_ _ _\/_ _ _|| /   /
              `.  \|'            `|/  .'
        _______/  _ >--------------< _  \______.##._
              ((((_(                )_))))   .##. |
            / ```` `--------------' ''''\   |  | |
            ( Welcome to Faisal's Bakery! \  |  |-'
            )                             ) `--'
            (          _        _.---.__.-'
            `-.___.--' `------'
        ";
      Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkBlue;
      Console.WriteLine(bakeryAscii);
      Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
      Console.WriteLine("Please [y] to place your order, [m] to view the menu and [n] to exit");
      string  continueAnswer = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
      if (continueAnswer == "y") {
        Console.WriteLine("How many loaves of bread would you like to purchase today?");
        string stringNumOfBread = Console.ReadLine(); 

        int numOfBread = 0;
        bool checkBreadInput = Int32.TryParse(stringNumOfBread, out numOfBread);
          if (checkBreadInput == true) {
            if (numOfBread >= 0 ) {
              Bread bread = new Bread();
              int breadPrice = bread.CalcBread(numOfBread);
              Console.WriteLine("You have bought " + numOfBread + " loaves of bread for: $" + breadPrice);
              Console.WriteLine("Would you like to buy some Pastry's today? [y] or [n]");
              string pastryAnswer = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
                if (pastryAnswer == "y") {
                  Console.WriteLine("Please enter the amount of pastry's you would like to buy:");
                  string stringNumOfPastry = Console.ReadLine(); 
                  int numOfPastry = 0;
                  bool checkPastryInput = Int32.TryParse(stringNumOfPastry, out numOfPastry);
                  if (checkPastryInput == true) {
                    if (numOfPastry >= 0) {
                      Pastry pastry = new Pastry();
                      int pastryPrice = pastry.CalcPastry(numOfPastry);
                      Console.WriteLine("You have bought " + numOfPastry + " pastry's");
                      Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
                      Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                      int total = breadPrice + pastryPrice;
                      Console.WriteLine("Your total bill is $" + total);
                      Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                      Console.WriteLine("Goodbye");
                    } else ErrorNegativeNumber(); 
                  } else Error();
                } 
                else if (pastryAnswer == "n") {
                    Console.WriteLine("Thank you for Coming in, your total bill is $" + breadPrice);
                    Console.WriteLine("Goodbye");
                  } else Error();
              } 
              else {   
              ErrorNegativeNumber();      
            } 
          } else Error();
      } else if (continueAnswer == "m") {
        Menu();
    } else if (continueAnswer == "n") {
      Console.WriteLine("Goodbye");
    } else {
      Error();
    }
}

    public static void Menu() {
      Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------");
      Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
        string menu = @"Fresh Bread: $5 each (loaf)
        Delicious Pastry: $2 each
        ** Special of the week **
        Bread: Buy 2, get 1 free!
        Pastry: 3 for $5!";
        Console.WriteLine(menu);
        Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to continue");
        string menuAnswer = Console.ReadLine();
        Main();
    }
        public static void Error() {
          Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
          Console.WriteLine("Error, Invalid Input");
          Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to Restart");
          Console.ReadLine();
          Main();
    }

        public static void ErrorNegativeNumber() {
          Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
          Console.WriteLine("Error, Invalid Input. Negative Input detected.  You owe us bread!");
          Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to Restart");
          Console.ReadLine();
          Main();
    }
    }
}
`````

This is the Program.CS file.

I can't seem to figure out how I can put all this stuff in classes files because I thought anything with Console.Read() or Console.Write() has to go into the program.cs file.

Comment: No you can put Console anywhere. However, that might not be the solution your assignment is looking for. Console is the UI, so your assignment says separate the UI from the business logic. That means you should have classes / functions that get called with parameters, and return something back (like text), that your UI controller then handles passing into the Console.

Comment: That makes sense.  

I think I will be taking out everything except the readline and the menu if statement structure.  

The rest I will put in functions and move out of main.  

I'm not sure if I would keep them in program.cs or in the classes files tho